# Trigger argument error. Date range not working

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I created a trigger that would insert a string to a table. So if its between january and may, it would insert '1st sem' on the table. and if its between june and july, it will insert 'Summer'. and between august and dec, it will insert '2nd Sem'.

This is what i tried so far.

```
CREATE TRIGGER acad_term
BEFORE INSERT ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) <= 5) THEN
SET NEW.academic_term = '1st Sem';
ELSEIF (MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) >= 8) THEN
SET NEW.academic_term = '2nd Sem';
ELSE
SET NEW.academic_term = 'Summer';
END IF;
END;
```

Im having an error of:

## SQL query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER acad_term
BEFORE INSERT ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) <= 5 THEN
SET NEW.academic_term = '1st Semester'
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

If anyone can please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: set before `DELIMITER  |` and after `| DELIMITER  ;`

Comment: @splash58 I get this error now #1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: and I have the latest xampp. so basically that's not possible?

Comment: say before all `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS acad_term;`

Comment: Yeah i had a trigger on the same table thats why. So i just joined both in one trigger and its now working. 2 triggers in one table is not allowed. dont know why but yeah that did it. Thanks so much man! @splash58

Comment: cant upvote your comment tho dont know why. just the flag on the left side of the comment @splash58